# "undefined reference to strerror_r" with OpenSSL-1.1.0e and MinGW

Tags: c, windows, openssl, mingw

While building OpenSSL-1.1.0d I am getting below error.

```
./libcrypto.a(o_str.o):o_str.c:(.text+0x5cb): undefined reference to `strerror_r'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile.shared:187: link_app.] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/MinGW/openssl-1.1.0d'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:5966: apps/openssl.exe] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/MinGW/openssl-1.1.0d'
make: *** [Makefile:128: all] Error 2
```

I followed the below steps to build it

1. `tar -xf vv.tar.gz`
2. `perl Configure mingw no-shared`
3. `make`

The instructions came from [Compiling OpenSSL on Windows (mingw32)](http://www.stringcat.com/company_blog/2015/12/07/compiling-openssl-on-windows-mingw32/).

Why is the link failing, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You tagged with `c++`. You ***must*** build the library with a C compiler; not a C++ compiler. MinGW was abandoned some time ago. Can you use Cygwin instead? The OpenSSL project has instructions for building with MinGW in [INSTALL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL) and [NOTES.WIN](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES.WIN). Can you use them instead? You may need to define `_XOPEN_SOURCE = 600`. Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: sorry c++ tag,thanks for your response..i gone throw your all suggestion but still i am getting same error.. :(    './libcrypto.a(o_str.o):o_str.c:(.text+0x5cb): undefined reference to `strerror_r''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strerror_r may not be implemented in mingw, you need  to check minwg latest documentation

Comment: thanks Pras.. it worked after changing to latest version of mingw ..  thanks to all...:)